# receive sms from multiple numbers in android

Tags: java, android, sms

using the following code i can update my application with sms from the inbox from a particular number,

```
String[] smsNo={"15555215556"};
        //for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                   Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,"address=?", smsNo, null);
        //Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( 
            //     Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );
        int date      = (cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.DATE));

        if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;

        smsList.clear();
        a = cursor.getString( indexAddr );
```

when i add another number in smsNo array ex: `smsNo={"15555215556","15555215558"};`

my application gets force closed. Iam trying to display all sms from a particular number in a ListView.

Comment: common guys.. Any further information, iam eager to share.. Atleast a few comments would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                   Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,"address='15555215556'", null, null);

Comment: But i need to include multiple numbers, in address.